# count click on link class on posts and add it to custom field

Tags: php, database, counter, custom-fields

I have 4 links on each of my posts (facebook, twitter, etc ...), what I'm trying to do, is that everytime someone click on one of this link, i'll have a counter incremented, and store the reslut in a custom field associated to the posts.

this way I'll be abble to display on each of my posts the number of clicks, and also to sort my posts depending of the clicks.

I know how to count with php, but I don't know how to store and update by custom field everytime a user clicks, and associate it to a custom field.

can anybody help me with this ?

thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: I would store the information in a database and then retrieve that information on the front end with AJAX. The onClick event would send a request to the backend, stored in the database, and then append +1 to the clickcount. The click count could also be accomplished fairly easily with some sort of service / google analytics. Have you tried looking into that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create field in your post table called views.
2. In your post page add-in a 'UPDATE' query that takes the current value of posts.views and increments it by one.

simple.

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you please be more specific ? I don't know how to do it, thanks a lot